# Keras model & Tensorflow Estimator - model response processing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

After creating the model in Keras, I use the `model_to_estimator` function to transform it into an Estimator. After training, the model is saved using the `export_savedmodel` function. Is there any way in which I could process the response provided by the model before it is forwarded ? I am looking for a solution similar to `serving_input_receiver_fn` in the `export_savedmodel` function, but instead of preprocessing the input I would like to process the model output.

Comment: Can't you use lambda layers at the end?

Comment: The problem is that it would have to be at the end of the network, behind the softmax layer. And that would affect the learning and evaluation process. So the Lambda layer should work only in the case of prediction, and I do not know if this can be done.